# Making a Variable in View Model Writtable Instead of Get-Only - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, viewmodel

What I'm trying to do is add an insert to an empty array variable in my view model through an if else statement. However when I try to add an inset, I get an error saying that my view model array variable is a get-only property.

My question is how can I make my variable in a read and write format so I can add inserts to it?  Thanks!

// ViewModel Variable

```
var selectedTimesOfDay: [String] {
   return jobService.selectedTimesOfDay
}
```

// My Function

```
@objc func handleContinue() {
        
   guard let jobService = jobService else { return }
   let viewModel = JobServiceViewModel(jobService: jobService)
        
   if morningButton.isSelected {
      viewModel.selectedTimesOfDay.insert("Morning", at: 0)
   }
        
}
```

Comment: `selectedTimesOfDay` is a computed property; that is it simply returns the contents of `jobService.selectedTimesOfDay`.  You should add a function to your view model that does whatever is required to the model property

Comment: So I should create a function to handle adding inserts to ```jobService.selectedTimesOfDay```?

Comment: Yes, that is what I would do.

Comment: Okay adding functions to view models is new to me, could you give me an example of what you would do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to put my view model variable in a setter and getter so it can be writable. Then set an empty array in the initializer so I can add an insert in my controller.

// View Model

```
var _selectedTimesOfDay: [String]

var selectTimesOfDay: [String] {
    set {
       _selectedTimesOfDay = newValue
    }
    get {
       return _selectedTimesOfDay
    }
}

init(jobService: JobService) {
    self.jobService = jobService
    self._selectedDate = ""
    self._selectedTimesOfDay = []
}
```